# naming advice "subtract absolute" type function

Tags: python, math

Is there a standard function or maths naming convention for a function which always moves the first input towards 0 by the amount of the second input.

```
def reduce(x, y):
    if x > 0:
        return x - y
    elif x < 0:
        return x + y
    else:
        return 0
```

It seems like quite a fundamental operation, but I can't find any examples of it.

If y is negative it would move further from 0. If y > x, the return value would have the opposite sign to x (overshoot 0).

Comment: @user3135460 That would be a copy and paste error ;) edited now, thanks

Comment: I'd call it `shift_towards_zero(number, delta)`. This is similar to "round towards zero" or "round away from infinity". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_towards_zero. As far as I'm aware, this functionality is not built into the `math` library. You'll need to roll your own. Do NOT name your function `reduce`, as this is a built-in function in Python. Also, is `y>=0`?

Comment: No not necessarily - for example, if x=10, y=5 result would be 5. if x=-10, y=5, result would be -5

Comment: good stuff @IceArdor, add it as an answer :)

Comment: If y is negative it would move further from 0

Comment: It's a shame that the word magnitude is so cumbersome, because this function is really "reduce_magnitude(number, amount)"...

Comment: @GreenAsJade Common sense tells me that -10 reduced by 2 should be -12, not -8 as intended. The number line doesn't fold back on itself at 0.

Comment: The magnitude of -10 is 10.  Reducing it's magnitude reduces it to -8.   -12 has a greated magnitude than -10.   That was the ling of thinking I was following.    Even more cumbersome would be "reduce_absolute_value()", if that is clearer than magnitude.

Comment: `reduce_magnitude` works (with a good docstring)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd call the function `shift_towards_zero(number, delta)`. This is similar to "round towards zero" or "round away from infinity". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_towards_zero. As far as I'm aware, this functionality is not built into the `math` library. You'll need to roll your own. Do NOT name your function `reduce`, as this is a built-in function in Python.

Here's how I would write the function:

```
def shift_towards_zero(number, delta):
    return sign(number) * (abs(number) - delta)
```

Here's how the function behaves:

- if delta is positive, shifts towards zero.
- if delta is negative, shifts away from zero
- if number is zero, return zero because number does not have a sign
- if abs(delta) > abs(number), the result will have the opposite sign of number (overshoot past zero)

Here's an input/output table of this function

```
number  delta result
 5        1     4  #delta>0 means shift toward zero
 5       11    -6  #overshoot
 5       -1     6  #delta<0 means shift away from zero
 5      -11    16
-5        1    -4
-5       11     6  #overshoot
-5       -1    -6
-5      -11   -16
 5        0     5
-5        0    -5
 0        1     0  #shift direction is undefined
 0       11     0
 0       -1     0
 0      -11     0
 0        0     0
```